# basic math question about voltage, ohms, resistance

Tags: voltage, resistance, math, ohms-law

total n00b here. After working on several projects by copy & paste from other people's schematics and code, I'm finally digging in and learning some of the math to know what I'm doing.

If I have a pushbutton ([this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/97), to be exact) that lists max amps as 50mA, and I have a 9 volt battery, the math for the resistor that I need is 9/0.05 == 180ohm, right?

Comment: Although, as a general guide line,  you should never design to maximums.  A factor of 2X in current should be sufficient so  \$360\Omega\$ would be safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you use the push button for? I doubt you need such high current and can easily do with much less, especially when you use it as input for a logic circuit. Although @rawbrawb's 360 ohm will probably work perfectly well, it does draw a lot of current from the power supply. When using a 9V battery, the cell will be drained very quickly.

*If* the push button indeed is only used for a logic level to drive an opamp or digital chip, a resistor of 10kΩ would already suffice. You didn't share the circuit diagram, that might help in deciding on a good value.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. I suggest you look up [Kirchhoff's current and voltage laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws). It should help quite a bit.

Comment: Kirchhoff's laws are a terrible thing to point a self-proclaimed  noob at-- what did he ever do to you?  There is certainly a time/place for those laws, but in this case Ohms law is more than adequate.